# PHP Validate comma serprated 10 digit Phone numbers

Tags: php, validation, pattern-matching

i am trying to handle from server side to check the string is in correct format or not for example

```
 $string = "9000010000,9100011000,9000020000      // Its correct pattern
 $string = "9000010000,9100011000,9000020000,   // Its WRONG   Reason comma in last place
 $string = ",9000010000,9100011000,9000020000,   // Its WRONG   Reason comma in first place
 $string = ",9000010000,9100011000,,9000020000,   // Its WRONG  Reason ,,
 $string = "9000010000,9100011,9000020000,   // Its WRONG because Middle no. is not 10 digit
```

i already did client side validation through JavaScript using this code

```
    var listIsOk=/^(\d{10},)*\d{10}$/.test(contact_list);
if(listIsOk==true){
alert("success"
}
else {
alert("string is wrong")
}
```

i want to know how i can achieve this on php thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (preg_match('/^(\d{10},)*\d{10}$/', $string)) {
  echo 'success';
} else {
  echo 'string is wrong';
}
```

Comment: No problem. It appears you got the pattern right anyway, you just needed the PHP function.

Answer (score 0):

Start by looking into the php function `explode()`, which will allow you to split your string into an array of phone numbers.  From there you'll need to loop through and look at each one to determine if it's correct.

Comment: i know, but is there any other way i can use regex or any other patten matching algorithm for this .. without using loop and checking each number thank you